# Slowing down a program (in c and assembly) using interrupts

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, x86-16, dosbox

I want to slow down a program using interrupts according to these conditions :

- if I press the up arrrow on the keyboard the speed will increase
- if I press the down arrow on the keyboard the speed will decrease

**I want to do it by using interrupts**: if the speed should decrease I will mask more interrupts and if the speed should increase I will unmask interrupts.
I know how to reach to the keyboard interrupt and to mask and unmask interrupts.
I just don't know how to reach the program speed.
I am writing the code in c and assembly.

Comment: What architecture and operating system are you programming for?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you ,I am programing in dos box

Comment: dosbox means emulation. You're asking how to configure dosbox to change speed with keys?

Comment: "how to reach the program speed" Hmm.. to me it's unclear what that means. You you asking about changing CPU clock frequency?

Comment: exactly,I want to Know how to get to the original speed

Comment: you're using an emulator. Speed regulation is the point of an emulator, specially dosbox.

Comment: DOSbox already has a feature to select the CPU speed.  While you can implement CPU slowdown by causing an artificial interrupt storm, it's a lot easier to just configure the emulator.  You can adjust the speed of DOSbox using Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12.

Comment: I know that there is an easier way to sow the speed down ,I need to use interrupts

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to *intercept* one of the interrupts such as the BIOS clock tick `int 08h` or (better) MS-DOS `int 1Ch` handler called at about 18 hertz. Then add time-wasting loops based on a variable that is controlled by certain keyboard events.

Make sure you re-enable interrupts before each delay.

At the end of the program you are responsible for restoring the original interrupt vector.

You can't speed a program up faster than its starting speed without adjusting the emulation.